# How to pass varargin through callback functions

Tags: matlab, callback, variadic-functions, cell-array, matlab-gui

I'm writing code for a graphics window with several GUI items which run callback functions.  Currently I've got a text box and a slider control, and I set things up so that a change to the text box value not only changes the data displayed but also updates the slider position to match that value.   The problem I'm running into is in trying to keep my `varargin` arguments (as entered to the main function when creating the graphics window) from being enclosed in a parent `cell` variable.  When my top-level `varargin` contains a Value-Parameter pair, `varargin` is a `cell` of dimension 1x2 .  That's fine.  Normally, one can pass all these arguments to an internal function call like this:

```
function topfunc(varargin)
%code
do_something(varargin{:})
```

And the function `dosomething` sees the correct list of arguments.  But when I pass the varargins thru the `callback` definition, as in

```
txtui = uicontrol(hf,'Style','edit','string',fristframe,'backgroundcolor','y',...
    'position',[10 100 50 20],'Tag','Scaler','UserData',lsatframe,...
    'Callback',{@doslide,adcname,mode,goodframes,{varargin{:}} } );
```

and then the function  `doslide` calls the plotting update function `dordplot`

```
 function doslide(theui,event,fileName,mode, goodframes,varargin)
% code snipped...

dordplot(slidinfo,event,fileName,mode,goodframes,varargin{:});
end
```

Inside `doslide`, `varargin` is a 1x1 cell containing the expected 1x2 cell .

I put in a kludge fix in my final function, where the contents of `varargin` are actually used, with the line

```
varargin = varargin{:};
```

But it seems wrong that `varargin` ever gets wrapped inside a cell in the first place.
Is there a fix, or did I define my callback function call incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the documentation for `varargin`:

> When the function executes, `varargin` is a `1-by-N` cell array, where `N`
>   is the number of inputs that the function receives after the
>   explicitly declared inputs.

In your callback declaration you have:

```
{@doslide,adcname,mode,goodframes,{varargin{:}}}
```

Wrapping `varargin{:}` in braces concatenates it back into a cell array, so you are only ever passing 1 input to `doslide` after `goodframes`.

Remove the braces:

```
{@doslide, adcname, mode, goodframes, varargin{:}}
```

Comment: Correct!  I'm embarrassed to have missed that -- I was doing a series of build&test ops and completely forgot I'd put that undesirable bit of code into what I was running.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 1):

In matlab, expressions with multiple-index cell indexation (`c{:}`,`c{array}`) of cell arrays are **value lists**. Value list is just a comma-separated list the of the cell array elements. For example, for cell array
`c={1,2,3,4}`
the value of `c{:}` is exatcly `1,2,3,4`. So the line `d= c{:}` means
`d=1,2,3,4`. It is an error.

UPD: I was not right, `d=1,2,3,4` is not an error, it is a way to express `d=1`. Anyway, `{varargin{:}}` is equivalent to `varargin`, because `varargin{:}` means comma-separated list of all elements of `varargin`